# Strange block page on OpenDNS?

Tags: dns

This morning I went to the internet and accidentally clicked on a blocked website (OpenDNS blocked it). 
Though there was something strange on the place of the icon there was a little router icon and there was written "Strona zablokowana przez administratora".
The rest of the page was the exact same.
I went to work and when I came back I was trying to found out how that was possible.
I did not remember what the site was so I used another (kickasstorrents.com was giving me the same thing).

I am using the OpenDNS parental control version (208.67.222.123) to block sites. So that the page is showing up is normal. I scanned my MAC and there was no virus (Norton + Avast).  I tried to go directly to block.opendns.com and the page was normal without the strange text and picture. When I clicked kickasstorrents.com the weird page did show up again. After that I did go directly to the block.opendns.com and the weird icon was still there. After clearing the cookies and history it was gone.

Every other page is showing up normal. When changing the DNS server to Google (8.8.8.8). The page is not showing up anymore (not even when clicked kickasstorrents.com).

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing unusual. What happened here was that a non-blocked loaded the blocked page inside a frame. This can cause the blockpage to inherit the favicon and title from the non-blocked page. This is not a security risk because a fake page could aswell spoof the favicon and title anyways instead of inheriting it from a Another site.

Clearing the cache does in most time solve the problem.